# Closing the Colorbox when clicking on its image

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I've got a colorbox which closes nicely with:

```
$.colorbox.close();
```

I also closes when clicking on the overlay, but I'd like to close it when clicking on the image. Were can I add the call to that close function?

Comment: inside image's click event handler..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would simply do this:

```
$('img').click(function() {
    $.colorbox.close();
});
```

Comment: I added your handler inside the onComplete handler when opening the colorbox. That did the trick, thanks.